# Running all expansions in AOE 3 from a single exe

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I am unable to play any campaign or to load any home city from *The Warchiefs* in *The Asian Dynasties* and vice versa. The main AOE 3 game is also unable to load any of the two expansions. Both expansions are working fine if I run them with their executables.

- Is there any way to play them from a single executable?
- Is this normal or is this caused by an installation problem?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [the AOE community forums](http://forum.agecommunity.com/forums/thread/882957.aspx), there is a way of allowing you to use the warchiefs races in asian dynasties. Here is how it is done:

- Run Regedit, and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft
  Games (everything will be under here)
- Go to Age of Empires 3 Expansion Pack 2/1.0 in and copy the PID
  value.
- Go to Age of Empires 3 Expansion Pack/1.0, create a string value with the name of PID. For the value, use the one you copied
- Go to Age of Empires 3 Expansion Pack 2/1.0, and copy the value
  DigitalProductID.
- Go to Age of Empires 3 Expansion Pack/1.0, right-click and create a binary
  value. Call it DigitalProductID and paste the copied value.

This will cause the asian dynasties to be your only executable (as all the WarChief files will now be copied over).

Comment: Just the caveat of "doing anything wrong in regedit can brick your computer"

Comment: Depending what it is. In this case, the worst case scenario is bricking AOE, but it all depends. If OP follows this, he should be fine.

Comment: @franglais, you can not brick a computer. At least, not in this way. Bricking means you can not fix something it. It is an expensive brick, and nothing more. Having a simple Backup disc of the operating system fixes even the worst-case scenario from changing reg files. The use of a live boot disc post-corruption can fix the problem, too.